# Python: Errors reading/writing file from python executable

Tags: python, linux, file-io, file-permissions, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a Python application that is executable. It reads and writes to a file. The application uses wx for a GUI and has been given the following permissions:

```
chmod +x app.py
```

When I load the application from the terminal like so:

```
./app.py
```

The application loads and causes no errors.

However, when I double click the app.py file and click 'execute', everything works perfectly except for the reading and writing of this file. This is a major part of the program and causes errors.

I cannot, for the life of me, understand why this is not working.

I have attempted to set it so that it loads as the root user each time with no luck. I have also been developing as the root user the entire time, so I shouldn't see any issues.

I am using the default Raspbian OS.

Comment: you open file with full or relative path?

Comment: is your desktop running as root too? usually it shouldn't be for security reasons, that means the process started by double clicking won't have root privileges and may not be allowed to read/write the files. scripts can't be suid'd, if that's what you've been trying to do.

Comment: I'm using the relative path - the file is located in the same directory as the application. I'll try change the path and see what that does.

Comment: If I cannot run this application with the desired privileges, how might I overcome the issue of storing information? That is the reason I'm using file access at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to modify the permissions of the file to be readable/writable/executable by the user you log into the GUI with.  Do some reading on [Linux File Permissions](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions) and see where that takes you.